# Search between lines beginning with a set character

Tags: windows, batch-file

first off I haven never really used batch but I'm trying to accomplish something and start to feel overwhelmed. 
I have a bunch of *txt files in Subdirectories. I want to search these *txt files for if they don't contain a certain string (ABCDEF) and output the results into a new file.

If a file **doesn't** contain ABCDEF:

> output the Filepath and Name as well as the content of every line that begins with "[".

If a file contains ABCDEF one or more times:

> Search between lines beginning with "[" for ABCDEF if **not found** output the first of the two lines beginning with "[" and move like that through the whole file.

Example

> My files look like this:
>
> > [ID1]
> >  
> >     text **not** containing abcdef
> >  
> >     [ID2]
> >  
> >     text containing abcdef
> >  
> >     [ID3]
> >  
> >     text **not** containing abcdef
>
> Here my sample output should be:
>
> > Filename
> >  
> >     [ID1]
> >  
> >     [ID3]

---

**Additional clarification of requirements**

I have a bunch of AD User Group Logs in different folders. These are exported at random times and saved as *.txt. These Files contain from just a few up to a few hundred lines and are all set up the same way (as displayed above).

What my idea in terms of pseudocode is, is the following:

```
Loop through all folders and subfolders
Go through the files file by file
var output    
var searchString = abcdef    
var currentfile = Current File Name/Path
While nextline != End of File{
    If currentline[0] = "["
    output = currentline
    While nextline[0] != "["
    If currentline.contains(searchString)
        If currentfile != 0{
        echo currentfile
        }    
    echo output
    currentfile = 0
    break
    else
    continue
    }
```

So pretty much: look for searchstring, if you find: output the last line before that began with "[" and then keep looking

---

<strike>To add what I have gotten so far: I managed to get the files containing the name and getting the first GUID since it is always the first line.
Sadly /v didn't work since as soon as a line doesn't contain the searchstring it evaluates as true.</strike>

**Edit** I got it so far as I now am able to get all files that don't contain my search string by replacing && with ||. <strike>Now if I get it to output all lines beginning with [ in those files I'm halfway there</strike> Done.
Now all I have to find is a way to search the blocks between the lines beginning with "[" and return the values if nothing is found. Maybe someone has a tip? ^^

This is my code so far:

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "SrcDir=my root directory"
set "FileType=txt"
set "SearchKey=abcdef"
set "LogFile=output.log"
set linenum=1

(for /R %%f in ("*.%FileType%") do (
type "%%~f" | findstr /c:"%SearchKey%" > NUL || (
echo %%~f & for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /r /b /c:"\[" "%%~f"') do echo %%a
)
)) > "%LogFile%"
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have only gotten to work to find the string and output the first line; I tried searching for files not containing the string with the parameter /v but it just gives me all the files: `(for /R %%f in ("*.%FileType%") do (
   type "%%~f" | findstr /V /c:"%SearchKey%" > NUL && (
     echo %%~f & type "%%f"|findrepl /o:%linenum%:%linenum%
   )
)) > "%LogFile%"`

Comment: Thanks for improving the question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disregarding the outer FOR loop, this can be done very efficiently with nothing but FINDSTR :) !

The key is a little known FINDSTR capability to search across line breaks (it functions somewhat like a regular expression look-ahead). I describe the feature at the bottom of my answer to [What are the undocumented features and limitations of the Windows FINDSTR command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8844873/1012053).

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "SrcDir=my root directory"
set "FileType=txt"
set "SearchKey=abcdef"
set "LogFile=output.log"

(set LF=^
%=This creates a linefeed character=%
)

(
  for /r "%SrcDir%" %%F in ("*.%FileType%") do (
    echo %%~fF
    cmd /v:on /c findstr /rvc:"!LF!.*%SearchKey%" "%%F"|findstr /b "["
    echo(
  )
) >"%LogFile%"
```

I solve the problem in two steps. The first FINDSTR returns all lines that do NOT precede a line containing your search key. That result is piped into a second FINDSTR that returns only lines that begin with `[`.

Each side of the pipe is executed in a new cmd.exe process with delayed expansion disabled. But the LF variable must be expanded using delayed expansion. That is why I explicitly execute the left side in a new cmd.exe session with delayed expansion enabled via `/v:on`.

Another option is my [JREPL.BAT regular expression text processing utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). It is pure script (hybrid batch/JScript) that runs natively on any Windows machine from XP onward - no 3rd party exe file required.

I only need a single call to JREPL for each file.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "SrcDir=my root directory"
set "FileType=txt"
set "SearchKey=abcdef"
set "LogFile=output.log"

set "find=^\[[^\r\n]*$(?!\r?\n[^\r\n]*%SearchKey%)"
set "repl="

(
  for /r "%SrcDir%" %%F in ("test*.%FileType%") do (
    echo %%~fF
    call jrepl find repl /v /m /match /f "%%F"
    echo(
  )
) >"%LogFile%"
```

If I got the requirements wrong, and all lines below `[id]` should be searched until the next `[id`], then the FINDSTR solution cannot be modified to work. But the JREPL search is easily modified to extend the search until the next `[id]` by simply changing the definition of FIND:

```
set "find=^\[[^\r\n]*$(?!(?:\n(?!\[)|.)*%SearchKey%)"
```

Comment: doesn't work correct if the searchkey isn't the first line of the section.

Comment: @Stephan - That is how I interpreted the requirements. If the search must continue until the next `[` line, then FINDSTR by itself will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I did get your jrepl.bat script and will look into it. Yes, Stephan is correct. The search should look for the string "between" lines beginning with [. I will clear up my requirements, sorry about that.

Comment: WOW. Your solution with JREPL worked perfectly. THANK you so much @dbenham 
I'm going to try to reproduce the logic behind your JREPL solution and will get back to you if I have a question and it is alright with you?

Answer (score 0):

can be done with a "flag"

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set searchkey=abcdef
set flag=1
for /r %%f in (*.txt) do (
  echo %%f
  set "key="
  for /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in ("%%f") do (
    echo %%a|find "[" >nul && (
      if not defined flag if defined key echo  !key!
      set "key=%%a"
      set "flag="
    )
    echo %%a|find "%searchkey%" >nul && set flag=1
  )
  if not defined flag if defined key echo  !key!
)
```

`key` remembers the last `[something]` line

For the `&&` and `||` thingy, see [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)

For the `!variable!` syntax see [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: You have some logic issues. `key` must be cleared before each inner loop. `key` should not be echoed if it is not defined. And the last `echo !key!` should only fire if `flag` is not defined.

Comment: @debenham: will check and edit - but not tonight anymore.

Comment: didn' let me sleep... :=)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)! Now I understand your logic and it's the same way I thought I could get it done.
Currently I have some trouble with the script: 
It just outputs all the file paths+ names, but not the IDs. 
Also it throws back an error in cmd stating `"The File C:\Mypath\NextpathhereItStopsAtSpace could not be found` 
It seems to miss a delimiter somewhere, since it stops reading the filepath at the first "Space" it encounters.

Comment: I managed to get it to work with dbenham's JREPL solution. Still thank you so much for your help and effort. You went exactly the route I wanted to go but couldn't figure out.

Comment: added support for filenames with spaces. Dbenhams JREPL solution is probably the best and was my first idea, but I'm not yet firm enough with REGEX to come up with a working solution myself.